# The method setCellType(int) from the type XSSFCell is deprecated

Tags: java, apache-poi

Which is the alternative to this deprecated code?

```
cell.setCellType(XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);

//... cell is of XSSFCell type
```

I am using Apache POI 3.17

Comment: [cell.setCellType(CellType.NUMERIC);](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFCell.html#setCellType-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType-)?

Comment: Your code works! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC` like following type:

```
setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);
```

hope this help you.

Answer (score 3):

'org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC' is deprecated. Use 'org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType.NUMERIC ' instead.

```
// import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType;
```

```
// tCell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC); // <-- deprecated
setCellType(CellType.NUMERIC);
```